# How would sender be notified of the action of ACCEPT and DECLINE by receiver?

Tags: ios, objective-c, multipeer-connectivity

In the multi-peer framework if sender sent invitation to receiver and receiver declines it.
So is there any way to check that receiver decline the invitation?

```
[self.browser invitePeer:peerID
                       toSession:self.session
                     withContext:nil
                         timeout:INVITE_TIMEOUT];
```

Answer (score 3):

Read the [`MCSession` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/multipeerconnectivity/mcsession?language=objc):

> If you use one of the framework’s browser objects for peer discovery, when a peer accepts an invitation, the session calls its delegate object’s `session:peer:didChangeState:` method with `MCSessionStateConnected` as the new state, along with an object that tells you which peer became connected.

And checking the [`session:peer:didChangeState:` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/multipeerconnectivity/mcsessiondelegate/1406958-session?language=objc), I see this:

> This delegate method is called with the following state values when the nearby peer’s state changes:
>
> - `MCSessionStateConnected`—the nearby peer accepted the invitation and is now connected to the session.
> - `MCSessionStateNotConnected`—the nearby peer declined the invitation, the connection could not be established, or a previously connected peer is no longer connected.